# take values from a string of characters separated from comma

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this string :

```
[ Quotazioni in euro riferite al 08/08/2017
""
Paese,Valuta,Codice ISO,Codice UIC,Quotazione,Convenzione di cambio,Nota
""
AFGHANISTAN,Afghani,AFN,115,80.8402,QuantitÃ  di valuta per 1 Euro
ALBANIA,Lek,ALL,047,132.275,QuantitÃ  di valuta per 1 ]
```

i wanna start from the sixth line and insert into variable 'Country' AFGHANISTAN and ALBANIA and into variable 'ID' AFN and ALL.
How i can do that in pl sql?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: i use oracle, sorry. i wrong

Comment: all records are same?

Comment: yes, all like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   v_string   VARCHAR2 (4000)
      := '[ Quotazioni in euro riferite al 08/08/2017
""
Paese,Valuta,Codice ISO,Codice UIC,Quotazione,Convenzione di cambio,Nota
""
AFGHANISTAN,Afghani,AFN,115,80.8402,QuantitÃ  di valuta per 1 Euro
ALBANIA,Lek,ALL,047,132.275,QuantitÃ  di valuta per 1 ]';

   country    VARCHAR2 (20);
   id         VARCHAR2 (5);
BEGIN
   FOR row
      IN (SELECT *
            FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (line6,
                                            '[^,]+',
                                            1,
                                            LEVEL)
                                fields,
                             ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) rn
                        FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_string,
                                                    '^.*$',
                                                    1,
                                                    5,
                                                    'm')
                                        line6
                                FROM DUAL)
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_string,
                                            '[^,]+',
                                            1,
                                            LEVEL)
                                IS NOT NULL) PIVOT (MAX (fields)
                                                FOR rn
                                                IN (1 AS field_1,
                                                   2 AS field_2,
                                                   3 AS field_3,
                                                   4 AS field_4,
                                                   5 AS field_5,
                                                   6 AS field_6)))
   LOOP
      country := row.field_1;
      id := row.field_3;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Your table design is not efficient and it is not a good data model you have here. All related records which are distinct must always be placed in proper columns and merged into a single string.

You can however achieve it like it is shown using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to split the string and `PIVOT` to convert those into appropriate fields as named columns.